# Rewrite Rule Spaces

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I created a rewrite rule in IIS because of some Russian spammers but the rule doesn't seem to work correctly because of a space between two parts to search and I was wondering how to overcome this

```
<rule name="Russian Referral Spam" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Windows+2002|Windows+2003|Windows+2004|Windows+2005|Windows+2006|Windows+2007|Windows+2009" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://stackoverflow.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Before, I never included the spaces between Windows and the fake version:

```
Windows 2002|Windows 2004...
```

and that would pickup on anyone with Windows in the useragent and redirect them. With adding the + to the rule even with backslash before it's not affecting the Russian spammers. How do I change the above rule so that it searches for 'Windows 2002|Windows 2004|Windows 2005|Windows 2006... If it was in a URL I could add %20

Here are a few real examples of the Russian Spam User Agents:

```
Mozilla/7.0 (compatible; MSIE2.00; Windows 2005)
Mozilla/8.0 (compatible; MSIE3.00; Windows 2006)
Mozilla/6.0 (compatible; MSIE7.00; Windows 2008)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE4.00; Windows 2005)
```

I am not using Apache but IIS so no mod-rewrite rules, please.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

On Expert Exchange it says try Windows\ 2006 or Windows\s2006. Will try these but I am waiting for the spammers to return to get the 100% answer but I know within IIS I can test the rules so I will try that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct. For space in regexp you can use `\` or `\s`. Your rule can be something like that:

```
<rule name="Russian Referral Spam" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Windows\s(2005|2008)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://stackoverflow.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```